# Table cells not wrapping text correctly in Chrome

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I have a table using bootstrap stylesheet, and it have come impossible to make make cells wrap correctly to text a Chrome. Anyway, it works perfect on IE and Firefox. You can see it here:

```
  <form action="todos" method="post">
                    <table class="table" border="1"> // Normal table  using bootstrap stylesheet
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>asdf</th>
                                <th>asdf<th>
                             ...
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                        <tr>
                          ...
                       </tbody>
```

[image: Content of the table]

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's look like using word-wrap: break-word; Try to set:

```
table td {
    word-wrap: normal;
}
```